# Touchpad does not work in ubuntu 20.04.2, Thinkpad T14 AMD

Tags: touchpad

I use Thinkpad T14, AMD version. But touchpad suddenly does not work.

- Extended mouse work
- I can see the device in command `cat /proc/bus/input/devices`

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0007 Version=01a1
N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event6 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=660800011000003
```

- Command `xinput list`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    \[master pointer  (3)\]

⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    \[slave  pointer  (2)\]

⎜   ↳ USB OPTICAL MOUSE                         id=10   \[slave  pointer  (2)\]

⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   \[slave  pointer  (2)\]

⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 ALPS TrackPoint                    id=13   \[slave  pointer  (2)\]

⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    \[master keyboard (2)\]

↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    \[slave  keyboard (3)\]

↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    \[slave  keyboard (3)\]

↳ Power Button                              id=7    \[slave  keyboard (3)\]

↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    \[slave  keyboard (3)\]

↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=9    \[slave  keyboard (3)\]

↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   \[slave  keyboard (3)\]

↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=14   \[slave  keyboard (3)\]
```

Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-lenovo-touchpad-issue-20-04/ This link helped

Removed xserver-xorg-input-synaptics, unplugged the auxiliary mouse and restart the laptop.

The touchpad is recognised and the main functions working.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1170090)